# SQL Select rows by comparison of value to aggregated function result

Tags: select, sqlite, group-by

I have a table listing (gameid, playerid, team, max_minions) and I want to get the players within each team that have the lowest max_minions (within each team, within each game). I.e. I want a list (gameid, team, playerid_with_lowest_minions) for each game/team combination.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM MinionView GROUP BY gameid, team
HAVING MIN(max_minions) = max_minions;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as it seems to select a random row from the available rows for each (gameid, team) and then does the HAVING comparison. If the randomly selected row doesn't match, it's simply skipped.

Using WHERE won't work either since you can't use aggregate functions within WHERE clauses.
LIMIT won't work since I have many more games and LIMIT limits the total number of rows returned.

Is there any way to do this without adding another table/view that contains (gameid, teamid, MIN(max_minions))?

Example data:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM MinionView;
gameid|playerid|team|champion|max_minions
21|49|100|Champ1|124
21|52|100|Champ2|18
21|53|100|Champ3|303
21|54|200|Champ4|356
21|57|200|Champ5|180
21|58|200|Champ6|21
64|49|100|Champ7|111
64|50|100|Champ8|208
64|53|100|Champ9|8
64|54|200|Champ0|226
64|55|200|ChampA|182
64|58|200|ChampB|15
...
```

Expected result (I mostly care about playerid, but included champion, max_minions here for better overview):

```
21|52|100|Champ2|18
21|58|200|Champ6|21
64|53|100|Champ9|8
64|58|200|ChampB|15
...
```

I'm using Sqlite3 under Python 3.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in SQL Server, hopefully the syntax works for you too:

```
SELECT
    MV.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            team, gameid, min(max_minions) as maxmin
        FROM
            MinionView
        GROUP BY
            team, gameid
    ) groups
    JOIN MinionView MV ON
        MV.team = groups.team
        AND MV.gameid = groups.gameid
        AND MV.max_minions = groups.maxmin
```

In words, first you make the usual grouping query (the nested one). At this point you have the min value for each group but you don't know to which row it belongs. For this you join with the original table and match the "keys" (team, game and min) to get the other columns as well.

Note that if a team will have more than one member with the same value for max_minions then all these rows will be selected. If you only want one of them then that's probably a bit more complicated.